# Userform controlled variables within a macro

Tags: vba, userform

Morning Guys,

I have ran into a small roadblock with my project. I'm new to VBA and am trying my best to 'learn by doing' but I cannot seem to get my head around macro/userform interactions.

I have a userform with one textbox and 9 checkboxes. This is supposed to show the userform, allow the user to dictate a sheet name, and (from a list of 9 users) select which is active or not (true or false).

In my main sub, I just have a

```
Allocator.show
```

command, as you may have guessed, allocator is my userform name.

Then I've sort of just been trying things so I don't know how right the rest of the userform code is;

```
Private Sub cbGo_Click()

Unload Allocator

End Sub

Private Sub cboxAlison_Click()

If Me.cboxAlison.Value = True Then
    AlisonYN = True
        Else
    AlisonYN = False
End If

End Sub

Private Sub cboxBeverly_Click()

If Me.cboxBeverly.Value = True Then
    BevelyYN = True
        Else
    BevelyYN = False
End If

End Sub

Private Sub cboxCallum_Click()

If Me.cboxCallum.Value = True Then
    CallumYN = True
        Else
    CallumYN = False
End If

End Sub

Private Sub cboxEllen_Click()

If Me.cboxEllen.Value = True Then
    EllenYN = True
        Else
    EllenYN = False
End If

End Sub

Private Sub cboxGeoff_Click()

If Me.cboxGeoff.Value = True Then
    GeoffYN = True
        Else
    GeoffYN = False
End If

End Sub

Private Sub cboxJames_Click()

If Me.cboxJames.Value = True Then
    JamesYN = True
        Else
    JamesYN = False
End If

End Sub

Private Sub cboxLouise_Click()

If Me.cboxLouise.Value = True Then
    LouiseYN = True
        Else
    LouiseYN = False
End If

End Sub

Private Sub cboxMick_Click()

If Me.cboxMick.Value = True Then
    MickYN = True
        Else
    MickYN = False
End If

End Sub

Private Sub cboxTammy_Click()

If Me.cboxTammy.Value = True Then
    TammyYN = True
        Else
    TammyYN = False
End If

End Sub

Private Sub tbRPName_Change()

End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

Dim GeoffYN, TammyYN, CallumYN, JamesYN, MickYN, AlisonYN, BeverlyYN, LouiseYN, EllenYN As Boolean
Dim RP_Name As String

Me.cboxGeoff.Value = True


Me.cboxTammy.Value = True


Me.cboxCallum.Value = True


Me.cboxJames.Value = True


Me.cboxMick.Value = False


Me.cboxAlison.Value = False


Me.cboxBeverly.Value = False


Me.cboxLouise.Value = False


Me.cboxEllen.Value = False

Me.tbRPName = ""

End Sub
```

All of the named user variables (xxxxYN) are public in my main module.

These are the variables I want to pull back into my main macro as true or false following the user checking the desired boxes, along with the name as a string, and then continue running the original macro.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, I seem to be taking myself round in circles at the moment!

PS if it helps, my userform looks like this;

[UserForm](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M18vl.png)

Cheers,

Callum

Comment: Do you get an error message or something? Where is your exact problem? Are your public variables empty? Also, I would use all these ifs in on the cb_GO Button

Comment: My variables are all empty, apologies, probably should have let you all know the problem. If I put my IFs inside the cbGo button can I leave the private subs for each of the cbox[nameYN] empty?

Comment: Actually, all of my variables are empty bar one, whose value doesn't change in accordance with the check boxes on the userform.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You wrote *"All of the named user variables (xxxxYN) are public in my main module."* But we see them declared in userform's `Sub UserForm_Initialize`, too:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

Dim GeoffYN, TammyYN, CallumYN, JamesYN, MickYN, AlisonYN, BeverlyYN, LouiseYN, EllenYN As Boolean
Dim RP_Name As Stringn
...
```

even if you declared the same variables as `Public` in any module, the Userform variables hide their Public *namsakes* so any Userform setting is not *"seen"* in other modules

so you'd better remove the Userform dimming statement of the "namesakes" and leave only the `Public` one

moreover in such a declaration statement as you used, every single variable not explicitly associated with a specific type is implicitly associated to a Variant type

so in the main module you should use a "dimming" statement like follows:

```
Public GeoffYN As Boolean, TammyYN As Boolean, CallumYN As Boolean, JamesYN As Boolean, MickYN As Boolean, AlisonYN As Boolean, BeverlyYN As Boolean, LouiseYN As Boolean, EllenYN As Boolean
```

---

---

But should all what above get you going, nevertheless I'd recommend you to switch to a "class" approach together with the use of Dictionary object, like follows

in the `Allocator` code pane place the following code

```
Option Explicit

Dim chkBoxes() As ChkBx_Class 'array of type "ChkBx_Class" which you define in a Class Module

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
Dim nControls As Integer, i As Integer
Dim namesArray As Variant, cbIniValues As Variant

UFInit = True

namesArray = Array("Geoff", "Tammy", "Callum", "James", "Mick", "Alison", "Beverly", "Louise", "Ellen") '<== set here the names to be associated to every CheckBox
cbIniValues = Array(True, True, True, True, False, False, False, False, False) '<== set here the initial values of checkboxes

nControls = UBound(namesArray) + 1 '<== retrieve the number of CheckBoxes you're going to consider in the Form
ReDim chkBoxes(1 To nControls) As ChkBx_Class 'redim the "ChkBx_Class" array
For i = 1 To nControls

    Set chkBoxes(i) = New ChkBx_Class 'initialize a new instance of 'ChkBoxClass' class and store it in the array i-th position
    With chkBoxes(i)
        Set .ChkBox = Me.Controls("CheckBox" & i) 'assign the correct CheckBox control to its "ChkBox" property
        .Name = namesArray(i - 1)  ' assign the Name property of the Checkbox

        .ChkBox.Value = cbIniValues(i - 1) 'set the checkbox correct initial value
         Me.Controls("Label" & i) = .Name ' set the corresponding label caption

         dealersDict.Add .Name, .ChkBox.Value ' fill the dictionary initial pair of Dealer-name/checkbox-value
    End With

Next i

Me.tbRPName.Text = ""

UFInit = False

End Sub


Private Sub cbGo_Click()

Me.Hide

End Sub
```

---

add a "Class Module" to your project

either clicking Insert-> Class Module in the VBA IDE main Ribbon menu

or right-clicking anywhere in the VBA IDE Project Window and selecting Insert -> Class Module in subsequent sub-menus

---

expand the "Class Module" node in the Project Window

if you don't see the Project Window you can open it by clicking View-> Project Window in the main ribbon menu, or press "Ctrl+R"

---

select the new Class you added (it should be some "Class1" or the likes) and change its name to "ChkBx_Class" in the Property Window "Name" textbox

if you don't see the Property Window you can open it by clicking View-> Property Window in the main ribbon menu or press "F4"

---

in the Class Module code pane place the following

```
Option Explicit

'declare class properties: they will be associated in every instance of this class.
Public WithEvents ChkBox As MSForms.CheckBox ' "ChkBox" is now a property of the class of type CheckBox. it's associated to events
Public Name As String

' events associated to ChkBox class property
Sub ChkBox_Click()
    If Not UFInit Then dealersDict.Item(Me.Name) = Me.ChkBox.Value ' set the dictionary pair of Dealer-name/checkbox-value
End Sub
```

---

edit your main sub module as follows

```
Option Explicit

Public dealersDict As New Scripting.Dictionary
Public UFInit As Boolean

Sub main()
myval = "io"
Dim myKey As Variant

Allocator.Show
Unload Allocator

For Each myKey In dealersDict
    MsgBox myKey & ": " & dealersDict(myKey)
Next myKey

End Sub
```

---

create a reference to Microsoft Scripting Runtime Library to use Dictionaries.

this is done by choosing Tools➜References command in the Visual Basic Editor (VBE) which pops up a dialog box in whose listbox you are to find "Microsoft Scripting Runtime" to put a check mark next and press OK.

---

run the main sub

whenever you need to retrieve the boolean value associated to a given *name* you just have to use

```
myBool = dealersDict(name)
```

where name can be:

- a string literal with the wanted name ("Alison", "Mick" , ..)
- a string variable whose value stores the wanted name, so that somewhere in your code you may have typed:

  `Dim name as string
     name = "Mick"`

---

such an approach gives you a lot of flexibility, since you only have to:

- set the *names* and their initial boolean values in those two arrays (`namesArray` and `cbIniValues`) in `UserForm_Initialize`
- make sure you have checkboxes named after "CheckBox1", "CheckBox2", and so on as well as have labels named after "label1", "Label2", and so on
- make sure that "CheckBoxX" is aligned with "LabelX"
- make sure `namesArray` and `cbIniValues` have the same items number as labels and checkboxes

Comment: As you suspected, the first part answered my question! I was defining variables all over the place and my userform subs were using the non-public defined variables of the same name.

I'm still trying to wrap my head around the class modules. Obviously that's the way to do it and will leave my code a lot tidier.

Comment: glad to be of help. And... I'd once more suggest you to consider the class &dictionary approach: it may seem quite articulated at the beginning (and it's certainly is, though not that much as you would find out) but it'll save you a lot of work when your code will need (and it certainly will!) enhancements and/or revisions

Answer (score 0):

IDK what the actual issue is, but I tried to recreate your issue and just decided to show you what I have. See if any of this helps you at all.

[image]

[image]

All of this code is in the userform code, not at the module level. When I change the check box values, the values are stored (outside of the main sub, which is validated in the "check" sub click event).

Answer (score 0):

To make you code a little shorter, you can directly assign the value of a checkbox to a variable

```
Dim test as Boolean
test = me.CheckBox1.Value
```

You can insert this into the code of your go button

Comment: That's a great tip, thanks! It really helps at the outset to learn these little pearls. No doubt my code is twice as long as it needs to be and is perhaps a little untidy. All this good practice is great help.